# how to setup angular ui-calendar on service portal in servicenow

Tags: servicenow, ui-calendar

I'm trying to use the ui-calendar on servicenow widget. but I don't know how to set it up in servicenow.

There's a related link similar to what I want: https://community.servicenow.com/thread/239276

My problem is that I don't know - how the UI script with the Angular "model" can be add to ServiceNow

I got the error in the javascript as `"_includes_sp.jsx?v=01-29-2017_2025&lp=Mon_Apr_24_07_31_45_PDT_2017&c=2_42:11973 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: uiCalendarConfigProvider <- uiCalendarConfig"`

Comment: another related problem, The thing is after I create a UI script, I'm not able to add it to the widget dependenciy.

Comment: https://community.servicenow.com/community/develop/blog/2016/06/22/writing-a-angularjs-custom-filter-for-service-portal

Comment: problem solved. just add UI script from the JS includes